# Trash mic quality on Ubuntu (20.04 + KDE), but sounds perfect on Windows

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a predator helios 300. I am running kubuntu on it, along with windows.

I noticed that the mic is absolute garbage on linux (I will include a recording below) but it works as intended on windows. I have tried playing with gain on pluse control, alsamixer and still no improvement.

Some info about my laptop -

Sound Chip - Realtek ALC295

OS - Ubuntu 20.04 KDE, running linux 5.11.0-38

I have posted the same issue on reddit, where I was able to include the recording. Do check it out.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/qmavxa/trash_mic_quality_on_ubuntu_2004_kde_but_sounds/

Answer (score 1):

Realtek ALC295 chipset driver was merged into linux kernel with the release of 5.13. Updating to that kernel version gave a huge improvement in audio quality. That along with enabling echo-noise cancellation (https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/09/how-to-enable-echo-noise-cancellation.html) gives some more improvement.

Its still not the same level of quality I get on windows. But I think this is because realtek/acer might have made a better driver, keeping in mind all the gain issues this microphone has.

I tweaked some values from alsamixer, and found a sweetspot. Still not perfect, its usable.

Big thanks to [kDE_TokaMak from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/kDE_TokaMak/) for letting me know about the driver being merged in kernel. And huge thanks to others who suggested noise cancellation module

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/qmavxa/trash_mic_quality_on_ubuntu_2004_kde_but_sounds/